# Boost equivalent of System::String::Format("{0:D9}", x);

Tags: c#, c++, boost

Does anyone know the boost equivalent of

```
System::String::Format("{0:D9}", x);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/format/doc/format.html). The syntax isn't exactly the same, but you should be able to do everything you need with it. You'd write `{0:D9}` as `%1$09d` for the *first* argument (it's 1 based instead of 0 based), zero-padded decimal number with at least 9 digits.

```
cout << format("%1$09d %1$09d") % x << endl;
```

That would print the value of `x` twice. You can also pad with spaces instead of zeros by either leaving out the `0` or replacing it with a space:

```
cout << format("%1$9d %1$ 9d") % x << endl;
```

Comment: @DoaWen, Thanks for your reply. Seems like many syntax mean the same thing. I tried to read over the Boost.Format document, but it get confusing.

Comment: Any question related to this. Does the boost format has an "=" operator?

Comment: @ABS - You can center alignment with `=` if that's what you're asking. If you're just wanting to compare the result to something else, you should be able to do that with the normal equality operator `==`. Otherwise, I don't know what you're asking—please clarify.

Comment: @DoaWen - my question is this: boost::format f1("something %1%") % x; boost::format f2 = f1; Is that possible?

Comment: @ABS - It looks like you're talking about an assignment operator / copy constructor. I'm not sure why you'd _want_ to do that, but it should work. Just try it! ;)

Comment: Ok, i just did a quick test. The copy constructor seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

`"{0:D9}"` means *"Decimal representation of zeroth passed element with minimal width = 9."*. Equivalent with using Boost is:

```
boost::format("%09d") % 42
```